# How to change only the year value in a POSIXct Value

Tags: r

I would like to change only the year format on a POSIX date-time value. I would like to change 2013-12-30 XX:XX:XX to 2012-12-30 XX:XX:XX . I would like this to be general as there are hundreds of incidences with different hours. Is this possible to do while keeping the column as a POSIX value

Comment: use `modifyList(as.POSIXlt(your_time),list(year=2012-1900))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to subtract a year from the current timestamp

```
df$time - lubridate::years(1)
```

---

If you want to change only specific date without changing the time we can use `sub`

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(sub("2013-12-30", "2012-12-30", df$time))
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer, I want to keep the hours and there are are other times as well. So the date has a 24-hour range and has apprx 250 occurrences. So I want to leave the hours as is and simply change the dates

Comment: @ThomasShort I don't see how it changes anything here. If you have values in dataframe called `df` with column `time` wouldn't `df$time - years(1)` work ?

Comment: @RonakShah would that affect the other dates that I dont want to change as well?

Comment: You should specify that in the question which dates you want to change and which you don't want to change. If you do `df$time - years(1)` it will change all the dates present in `time` column. Do you want to change dates only with year 2013 ?

Comment: @ RonakShah  I apologize for that, in the future, I will be clearer in my question. To answer your comment, I only wish to change the 2013-12-30 to 2012-12-30, as there are 2013 dates that are relevant to my project. The data set runs from October 2012 to March 2013, however when downloaded from the API its skips the 30th of December 2012 and instead gives a value from the 30th of December 2013. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @ThomasShort Okay..updated the answer so that it changes only one specific date of `"2013-12-30"` to `"2012-12-30"`

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Base R. Convert to POSIXlt, subtract one from the year component and convert back to POSIXct.  No packages are used.

```
yearMinus <- function(x, n = 1) {
  lt <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  lt$year <- lt$year - n
  as.POSIXct(lt)
}

# test 
datetimes <- as.POSIXct( c("2013-12-30 03:02:01", "2013-12-30 03:02:01") )
yearMinus(datetimes)
## [1] "2012-12-30 03:02:01 EST" "2012-12-30 03:02:01 EST"
```

**2) gsubfn**  Convert to character, match 4 digits, convert the match to numeric and subtract 1 (done in the second argument which represents the transformation in formula notation) and then convert back to POSIXct.  This is done in one gsubfn call.

```
library(gsubfn)

as.POSIXct(gsubfn("\\d{4}", ~ as.numeric(year) - 1, as.character(datetimes)))
## [1] "2012-12-30 03:02:01 EST" "2012-12-30 03:02:01 EST"
```